# List Addition in python

Tags: string, list, function, type-conversion

I am trying to create a function that will add two list such that if list1 is [9,1,2] and list2 is [8,5,3] then the two lists added together would produce a list yielding. ]1,7,6,5] since 912+853= 1765.

The following is the code I have written:

```
def list_addition(list1,list2):
    otlist1=''
    otlist2=''
    for items1 in list1:
        otlist1+= items1
    for items2 in otlist2:
        otlist2+= items2
    strinum = int(otlist1)+ int(otlist2)
    return strinum

print(list_addition(['3','6','7'], ['4','9','0']))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chuck/PycharmProjects/arrayaddition/Arrays.py", line 13, in <module>
    list_addition(['3','6','7'], ['4','9','0'])
  File "C:/Users/Chuck/PycharmProjects/arrayaddition/Arrays.py", line 10, in list_addition
    strinum = int(otlist1)+ int(otlist2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I obviously know my code even if it did work as written wouldn't be complete as I would still need to put in the final codes to convert the integer variable 'strinum' back to a list, but I can't get there if my code is failing to properly add the two converted lists. When I break down the code and write the two for loops separately, convert them to integers and add them everything works perfectly fine. So the code below was good:

```
list1=['7','9','6']
otlist1=''
for items1 in list1:
        otlist1+= items1
print(otlist1)


ist1=['5','7','0']
otlist2=''
for items1 in ist1:
        otlist2+= items1
print(otlist2)
print(int(otlist1) + int(otlist2))
```

But for some reason when I try to put the two for loops inside a single function I get the error. I am a complete newbie to programming and I want to know what I am not understanding about function syntax. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be a typo. Look at the line `for items2 in otlist2:`. `otlist2` is empty, so that loop will never be entered. That means under the loop you're trying to do `int("")`, which will cause that error. I'm assuming you meant `for items2 in list2:`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Carcigenicate. I can't believe I didn't catch that typo myself. I must have spent a good half hour proofreading that function yesterday but didn't see that typo. I thought the error had to be structural. At least I can move on to a new exercise now. Learning to code is very interconnected so I  don't feel comfortable moving on when I don't fully understand why code i think should work doesn't work.  Gaps in knowledge are a killer.